# Is there any Portable IronPython Availabe?

Tags: python, ironpython, portable-applications

I have developed an application where a small part of the solution is done in `ironpython`, but when I am migrating to production they (client) are not giving permission to install `ironpython`.

I am trying to get any portable version of IronPython. So that without installing I can run IronP` code.

Please Help.

Comment: I've found  [this answer](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/14539.aspx). It boils down to _no need for IP on the client_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to MSI-install IronPython on the clients you are deploying your application to.

Just [XCOPY deploy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY_deployment) your application as well as required portions of IronPython (e.g. by grabbing a [current ZIP release](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/releases/download/ipy-2.7.5/IronPython-2.7.5.zip) or getting files from your local installation).

The required files will at least include

- `IronPython.dll`,
- `Microsoft.Dynamic.dll`,
- `Microsoft.Scripting.dll` and
- `Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata.dll`

from the correct `Platforms`-subfolder (e.g. `Net45`).

If the python standard library is used in your python code (or needs to be available to dynamically loaded code) the `Lib`-folder (or a subset) has to be included as well.

Should your application be deployed via MSI or a similar mechanism just include relevant IronPython files instead of XCOPYing.